# nuget and source control?

Tags: .net, version-control, nuget

I remember nuget not working as expected so I don't include it in my source control. But is there a way to make it work? I tried testing the problem. It seems if I delete my bin and object folder for my project i can compile no problem. However if I delete those and the dlls in packages it doesn't. If I have to include the binaries then whats the point?

Is there a way to get nuget to work when I don't have the dlls in the solution? I readd everything to nuget when I do a clean checkout everytime which is rare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you're after is "Enable NuGet Package Restore" within Visual Studio:

- Go to Solution Explorer
- Right-click on the solution
- Click "Enable NuGet Package Restore"

  [image: NuGet option]

This will allow automatic downloading of NuGet packages during the build process.

Comment: It looks like it works. As long as I include `.nuget` and the exe in it

Comment: Yes - you end up with one folder and 3 (I think) files. We use this option running msbuild.exe in Jenkins, to pull packages down automatically after downloading source from GitHub.

Comment: If you look in the .nuget\nuget.targets file, there is an option in there that you can edit (or pass in via the command line or as a property value) to have nuget.exe downloaded as part of the build process - so then you don't have to commit nuget.exe.